# Can't filter on a Date dimension in an Excel PivotTable based on a SSAS 2008 R2 source

Tags: excel, tfs, ssas, pivot-table

I have a spreadsheet which sources data for a pivot table from a SSAS 2008 R2 cube, and contains a date dimension from that cube in the 'Row Labels' section of the pivottable.

I want to filter this date on a date range using the 'between' filter, but when I do so there are always NO records shown- regardless of the fact that there are values that meet that criteria that I can see when I don't have any filter applied.

It isn't just the 'between' filter either- none of the date filters return results.

If I set a value filter instead of a date filter and use the serial number of the date (so between 40544 and 40575 for between 1/1/2011 and 1/2/2011 for example) then the filter is applied correctly.

Does anyone know why the date filter isn't working though?

BTW- this is for a TFS worksheet- the Iteration Backlog worksheet- which comes with the Microsoft Agile Process Template which I am editing. It currently doesn't load the burndown chart and I believe that this is why.

Answer (score 0):

Your believe is right, I had this problem, too. After several work, I recognized that this seems to have something to do with localization differences between my computer and the TFS cube. When you look into the vba code behind, you will find a twek concerning exactly that. I *think* I executed this method manually and the filters worked, but I can't say for sure. But finally, my date filter applies correctly.

Workaround for anybody who can't get it to work:
Add a Date hierarchy filter to the pivot table ("BurndownData") and disable the automatic burndown updates. Now you can set the burndown date range using the filter (set to same range as "Settings" page dates) and update the burndown data using "Data - Update all".
voilà, burndown shown.

btw: the BurndownData sheed is set to "VeryHidden", you can display it using the vba editor, click on BurndownData sheet, set Property "Visibility". This has no other side effect at all except you can see it.